# what is the default path for curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "cacert.pem");

Tags: c++, libcurl

Where does this command look for the pem file ? 
It is not in the folder where the dll runs. 
When I use full path it works, when I use relative path - either like in the Title or ./cacert.pem)
I get Error 77: CURLE_SSL_CACERT_BADFILE

What is the right way to specify relative path for this file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, It looks like using a relative path works BUT.... When you run it under debugger it is not your $(solutiondir)/Debug folder ! so it should be on the same folder of your EXE when you run it, but when you debug, you need to put it also on another directory (I've put it on solution and project dir and it worked)

Answer (score 0):

Specifying a relative path there is asking for trouble. But it'd then use the relative path from whereever it is executed (no surprise there really).

Possibly the SSL library your libcurl is built to use doesn't even like a relative path.

Comment: I can't use full path, as I don't know in which drive my app will be installed. I've put everything in the installation directory (purl, and ssl dlls ) so it won't need to look for anything in the computer, but when I try to read the file from there. either without the . or with it. it doesn't find it.