# using FULL Path with libCurl CURLOPT_CAINFO doesn't work

Tags: curl, libcurl

Since using the default path ([SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18865682/what-is-the-default-path-for-curl-easy-setoptcurl-curlopt-cainfo-cacert-pem) is troublesome in several scenarios, 
I've used GetModuleHandleExA to get the actual path of the dll.

removed the dll name and added the cacert.pem, sending it to :

```
        string myPath;
    myPath= GetModulePath();
    myPath.erase(myPath.size()-11,11);
    myPath += "cacert.pem";
    res = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO,  myPath);
```

The path is right (cut it from debug and run it using notepad + paste ) and got the file.

Yet I still get Error 77.

** UPDATE:
I did check it with regular Path and it works. so the actual problem is why using a string messes it up...

Any ideas how to solve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

myPath.c_str() solves this ! (send the char version of the string..)